# jPlayer mp3 not loading

Tags: jquery, html, mp3, jplayer

After further investigation, I've realized it's to do with the flash plugin not working, but again only in XP. You can see the code here: http://tarsusempire.co.uk/test/test.html

It works fine in OSX, but not XP. Both browsers are same version and so is flash. I've tried it in FF, Chrome and Safari on OSX, but not at all on XP.

Comment: Did you complain to [tag:jPlayer] yet?

Comment: Could you post the link? I think it's the file itself, not the script.

Comment: it just worked first time for me in IE8 on XP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be my flash plugin had upgraded itself and then needed for a simple computer reboot. So yes, turning it off and on again resolved this :)

Comment: Also, I should point out, that at some points I was doing this through remote desktop, and flash seems to not always work when on a computer through remote desktop. Some administrator rights or something.